# Why are const/let VariableDeclarations in AST trees and not LexicalDeclarations like in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, abstract-syntax-tree

In ECMAScript only var is a 'VariableDeclaration' and const/let are 'LexicalDeclaration' types.

[const/let](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations)

[var](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement)

However, i've been learning about AST trees and noticed that estree and babel parser both define const/let under 'Variable Declarations' .

[estree](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/f82448cbaa34b25482fdb45be5835906d0a2d197/es2015.md#variabledeclaration)

[babel-parser](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-parser/ast/spec.md#variabledeclaration)

Shouldn't the node types correspond to ECMAScript node types or am I misunderstanding how AST trees are built?

Comment: Relevant: http://astexplorer.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the node types correspond to ECMAScript node types

The specification of the AST format is entirely independent of the language grammar definitions. Often the two end up with correlation, but it is not the overall goal that they match up.

In the context of ESTree, you'd use `.kind` to differentiate the various types, instead of having a different node type, though that would certainly be an alternative approach.

Comment: +1, you're the authoritative source                                                                          
  :-)